# How to display SMD footprints in Eagle CAD as separate layer instead TOP or BOTTOM

Tags: eaglecad

I would like to print Pads, Vias, SMD footprints altogether so that I can apply UV solder mask on board. The problem is that the SMD footprints is part of TOP layer.

What to do?

Looks like correct layer would be tStop, but it appears stripped instead of filled. Looks like I should use some image editing software to fill those pads manually.. .

Comment: what's wrong with the solder mask layer?

Comment: VladimirCravero tStop layer displays border around pads with striped texture. I need it to be filled so that I can print filled "boxes".

Comment: @chba Print out the .GTS / .GBS (top and bottom soldermask) gerber in black and white. Invert colours in any standard image processing software. Will that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, the correct layer to use for solder mask are `tStop` and `bStop`.

In many cases these layers are visualised in Eagle as hatched lines which is not what you want for printing. However it is very easy to remove this and print them out as solid. Simply check the `Solid` option in the print dialog:

[image: Printing Solid]

Comment: Interestingly, printing to a PDF results in a solid image (even when the Solid option is not checked)... I was curious so I tried printing to a printer and indeed the hatched lines appeared... Maybe it's an Adobe Viewer thing.

Comment: @KnightsValour thatis interesting. Just tried it. With the Acrobat printer and without the solid option I get crosshatched lines but they are filled white (not transparent) which is a bit odd.

Comment: Whelp - apparently the type of printer you choose determines what happens. If you choose the "Print to File (PDF)" printer, you'll get filled-in polygons regardless of the "Solid" check mark option. If you use "Adobe PDF" as the printer, it behaves as expected (hatched lines are shown as such, unless the "Solid" option is checked). Gah, I'm sticking to Gerbers...

Answer (score 1):

tStop is normally used for the solder mask layer in Eagle. It is usual for it to be inverted. The board fab will understand this.

Comment: Yes! But the thing is, I would like to print that layer on transparent film so that I can cure UV mask. I am doing it all by my self, manually.

Comment: Does Eagle have an option to print it inverted?

Comment: Does not sound like inverted option will fill those tStop layer boxes.

Comment: When you say the boxes have a striped texture do you mean on the screen? If you print out tStop what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

If your "print" flow is not solidifing a hatched layer with the already suggested settings, or if you prefer to use the image export capability, you can change the fill style of any layer in the layers dialog.

Another approach can be to run a traditional CAM job and use something else to render a resulting gerber to pixels or whatever your printer understands.